# How to know if the msg sent in the firebase db is my msg or others msg

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I m making  a chat application in the main activity I am getting a data from a node:"chatnode", in that node all the chats are present and if anyone writes a chat its data is also being stored in that node and later can be seen in a recycler view !, what i want to do is that i want to detect that the data which is being given in the recycler view is 'mychat' (chat sent by me) or 'others chat'(chat sent by someone else), and once i detect that i want to set different views for the recycler view for eg- left side view for 'others chat' right side view for 'mychat'!

```
public class Chat_Adapter extends 
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Chat_Model,Chat_Adapter.myViewHolder> {

public Chat_Adapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Chat_Model> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Chat_Model model) {
    holder.date.setText(model.getDate());
    holder.uname.setText(model.getUname());
    holder.msg.setText(model.getMsg());
}

@NonNull
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_item, parent, false);

/*i have another view which is View view = 
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mychat_item, parent, false);*/
    
 return new myViewHolder(view);
}

class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView uname, date,msg;

    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        uname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.named);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        msg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message);
    }
}
```

}

in this adapter class there is an activity in which we can set the views!

what i tried-
i tried to get the 'uname' which is the name of the user who sent the chat, and my own name which i got from the sharedprefs , but i am unable to get the 'uname' in oncreatviewHolder method because the onbindviewholder method runs after the oncreateviewholder method so it crashes!

brief what i want to do !
I want to get the data from a node in my firebase db and detect if that data is sent by me or another user!, if sent my me then it should be on the right side of the recyclerview but if sent by other user then it should be on the left side of the recyler view as it happens in other chat app ! hope u get what i mean to say

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: The code works fine, I just want a way in which I can detect if the message is uploaded by me Or any other user